# How do I set up an MTS MBlaze modem?

Tags: networking, usb-modem

I have a new MTS MBlaze Broadband modem USB and it is not getting detected in my Ubuntu 10. 04. It is getting detected as an USB but not as MODEM as result I am not able to create a MOBILE BROADBAND connection

How to use MTS MBlaze modem on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

There two ways to setup MBlaze USB Modem in Ubuntu:

1. Using driver software which included in the modem itself.
   (Recommended)
2. And without any driver software.

### Using recommended driver software

The modem itself contains the driver software for both RPM and DEB based GNULinux distros, Mac OS and Windows. From these, we Ubuntu users, have to install `CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-i386-ubuntu.deb` package. If you are using 32 bit Ubuntu then it is not going to be a big headache. Just install it after connecting the USB Modem. But, if you have 64 bit Ubuntu then this one is not going to work as it is build for 32 bit systems only. For that we need to re-build this 32 bit only into 64 bit also driver software.

## For Non-advanced users

If you are not familiar with executing commands in terminal or do not want to spend your valuable time, simply download the package provided below which we had re-built ourselves.

### [Download CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-ALL-ubuntu.deb](https://rapidshare.com/files/514013822/CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-ALL-ubuntu.deb)

And install this after connecting the modem. It will work for sure because we are using it right now.

### For Advanced users

1. First we need to install **Dpkg**. Dpkg is a terminal based application
   that help to install, remove, unpack, build the *.deb package files.
2. To install Dpkg, connect to Internet and execute `sudo apt-get
   install dpkg` in terminal.
3. Extract *CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-i386-ubuntu.deb* file.
4. Open extracted directory->DEBIAN and open control file in a text
   editor.
5. Now replace the Architecture from **`i386`** to **`all`**.[image]
6. Save the file and close it.
7. In terminal, execute `sudo dpkg -b <extracted directory name> <deb
   filename>`
   For example, `sudo dpkg -b CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-i386-ubuntu CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-ALL-ubuntu.deb`

You may now find a new `CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-All-ubuntu.deb` file has built along with the extracted directory. This is the same one which we have provided above to download. Install this driver package after connecting the USB Modem.

And remember, you can also use this package for any other Ubuntu based distros.

### Without any driver software

MTS MBlaze USB Modem also can be used without installing driver software since latest version of Ubuntu (or any other GNULinux distro) support this modem by default. It should be at least 10.04 or greater version of Ubuntu.

1. Connect the modem with the PC. The system will detect the device
   automatically.
2. Look out for the notification saying *Device recognized USB Modem,
   ONDA Communication S.p.A.*, then click on the icon of Network
   Connections in system tray.
3. You will find an option *New Mobile Broadband (CDMA) Connection*,
   click on it.
4. A new window will open to setup a mobile broadband connection. Click
   Forward button
5. Select **India** as country, then Forward,
6. Select **MTS MBlaze** from the providers’ list, Forward,
7. And then click Apply,
8. Now Disconnect the connection which is trying to connect
   automatically. Because it is not going work until we provide
   username and password.
9. Open Edit **Connections**->**Mobile Broadband** (Tab)->Select **MTS MBlaze
   Connection** and click on **Edit**.
10. Under Mobile Broadband, type **`internet@internet.mtsindia.in`** as
     **username** and **`MTS`** as **password**.
    [image]
11. Check *Available to all users* and *Connect automatically* if you want.
12. Save it and close Network Connections.
13. Now take off the modem from the port and reconnect it.
14. After the modem get recognised by the system, try to connect
     Internet.
15. If everything goes right, you will see that your Internet
     connection will get connected.[image]

Happy Browsing. :)

Source: [How to setup MTS MBlaze USB Modem in Ubuntu GNULinux](http://www.e-dirts.com/2012/how-to-setup-mts-mblaze-usb-modem-in-ubuntu-gnulinux/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an another method to setup  mts modem in ubuntu

Here is the step by step procedure to install or set up MTSmblaze modem UI in ubuntu.

**step 1** : before installation you need the driver software for GNU/Linux distributions. The modem itself contains the driver software or download it from the following link.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e60tru2abkmn6hw/Mblaze%20UI%20files.zip

**step 2** :Just download and copy to `/home`. Connect the modem with the PC. The system will detect the device automatically.  Now type the following command in terminal to find out your modem:

```
 sudo lsusb
```

**step 3** : That will list down your MTSMblaze Modem as `Bus 002 Device 006: ID 19d2:fff1 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM`. You have to install MTSMblazeUI from the MTSMblazeUI folder (downloaded from the above link). Before that login to root in terminal. Run the following command in the terminal to login :

```
   sudo su
```

**step 4** : Then enter your password. Run below  command in TERMINAL to install  MTSMblazeUI as follows:

```
   sudo sh /path/to/mtsmblaze-autorun.sh /
```

`/path to/` is the path to autorun.sh inside the mtsmblaze folder that you have downloaded from the above link .

**step 5** :After executing the command the installation  procedure will start.

**step 6** : After finishing the installation remove the modem from the port and restart and reconnect it again. Open MTSMblaze UI from the dash.

**step 7** :Connection will get established itself and a message `connection name active will come on the screen` if everything goes right.

You will see that your Internet connection will get connected.

**source : https://emilgeorgejames.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/how-to-install-mtsmblazeultra-modem-in-deepin-linux-2014/**

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to connect in ubuntu 11.04

1. plug in the modem and wait for few seconds
2. on the taskbar we have the icon for network connection
3. just click on it and a window will popup
4. select mobile broadband in the window
5. your modem(mine mts mblaze) will probably be displayed
6. select country and apply
7. credential window will popup fill in username(internet@internet.mtsindia.in),password(mts),number(#777),also check on the upper part of this window the automatic connection checkbox.
8. save it

Answer (score 1):

Permanent solutions is going to be usb-modswitch if U r only using MTS or Reliance. If U go for GSM modems like Docomo, Vodafone or Airtel then U may face problem with modswitching. The U need to remove mod switch. So its going to be little tricky. I am in search for a permanent solution for both issues. Will post here if I get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new mobile broadband connection only after you installed [usb-modeswitch package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/usb-modeswitch) - install from Software Center: [usb-modeswitch](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/usb-modeswitch), review [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1448711) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ejecting the modem? Do not unmount. Simply eject the USB mode which will result in the modem be recognized as a modem. Then it will be available as an internet connection in your favorite Network Manager.

The setup then will be achieved by simply clicking on the connection and following easy setup process.

This worked for me in the Huawei Modems listed here: [How do i configure huawei usb modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31875/how-do-i-configure-huawei-usb-modem/31887#31887)

Give ejecting a try and please inform.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work for EC-156 devices (tested on MTS and Tata Photon).

Please ensure that you have installed the following packages

> - usb-modeswitch-data
> - usb-modeswitch

Connect the device and see whether it is detected automatically in the network manager
if not do the following things.
.Open the terminal
.Type

Code:

```
sudo nautilus
```

A new window will be opened for root
.Go to filesystems ----/etc/usb_modeswitch.d
.Create a new config file named 12d1:1505
.Cut and Paste the following

Code:

```
DefaultVendor= 0x12d1 
DefaultProduct=0x1505 
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

Save the file.

Go to terminal.

Go to the path by the code

Code:

```
cd /etc/usb_modeswitch.d
```

.Type the command

Code:

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -I -W -c 12d1\:1505
```

It may connect automatically...

Just wait for one minute.

The default network manager may detect your device and follow the instructions by it
mark it to connect automatically in the mobile broadband edit options.
If not open your network mannager go to manage connection
open the mobile broadband and add a new connection
if it detects installed CDMA device or Huawei EC156 follow the instruction given by the network manager
mark it to connect automatically in the mobile broadband edit options

**{

For MBLAZE:

username:internet@internet.mtsindia.in

password:MTS

}**

Reboot your system and see it is connected automatically.
If not you have to type the two codes mentioned above all the times when you connect your device.
It will be very diffficult to type the codes all the time....so go for the following steps to run that commands automattically

STEPS
Script to run the modeswitch command in boot
steps

1. Open the gedit.
2. Type the two commands which you want to run in two separate lines.
3. save the file with the extension .sh on the disk where ever you want and make this file as executable in the properties.
4. Then right click on the desktop.
5. Create launcher.
6. Set type as Run in terminal.
7. Give your desired name.
8. Give the path of file with the extension .sh in the command box.
9. Hit ok.

Open the launcher.....
enter the password if required

You can change your icon in the properties of the new launcher file

Connect your device when ever required and click the new icon on the desktop
Hit the password.....
enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

**A script to automate installing MTS Mblaze UI in linux**

This is a simple  automated shell script to install  mts mblaze UI automatically in your linux .The installation script will setup everything but you just need to choose some options (interactively) from setup, I hope no one will get any problem with it. It can work for all Linux desktops environments.

```
#!/bin/bash   
echo "
echo "MTS MBLAZE WIRELESSS DATA USB MODEM TERMINAL INSTALLATION GUIDE"
echo ""
echo "Select model for your MTS MBLAZE modem"
sleep 2
echo ""
echo "There are two types of modem "
echo "
 `printf "1"``echo ""` MTS-MBLAZE-MINI"
 `printf "2"``echo ""` MTS -MBLAZE-ULTRA"
echo ""
sleep 1
echo "Type (1 to 2): "
while read Input
do
# for mts-mblaze-mini

if [ $Input = "1" ]; then
{
echo "You have selcted MTS-MBLAZE-MINI"
sleep 1
echo "starting installation.................. "
sleep 1
echo "Downloading and installing ............"
sleep 2
cd && wget -O Linux.zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/2osuilo99kc3h15/Linux.zip?dl=0
unzip -o Linux.zip -d $HOME/
rm Linux.zip
cd && wget -O install_linux.sh https://www.dropbox.com/s/jk0wrpcok02r6wt/install_linux.sh?dl=0
cd && chmod +x install_linux.sh && ./install_linux.sh
}
break;
# for mts-mblaze-ultra

elif [ $Input = "2" ]; then
{
echo "You have selcted MTS-MBLAZE-ULTRA"
sleep 1
echo " starting installation................"
sleep 1
echo "Downloading and installing ....."
sleep 2
cd && wget -O Linuxx.zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/yirj4d1cpet1i1a/Linuxx.zip?dl=0
unzip -o Linuxx.zip -d $HOME/
rm Linuxx.zip
cd && wget -O install_linux2.sh https://www.dropbox.com/s/tuggjr3jqdnlwil/install_linux2.sh?dl=0
cd && chmod +x install_linux2.sh && ./install_linux2.sh
}
break;
else
echo "Input is invalid!!!"
echo "Type right model of modem."
echo ""
echo "Type from (1 to 2): "
fi # closed
done # all done
```

To install MTS Mblaze UI in Debian/Ubuntu/Linux Mint/deepin/LMDE/Any Linux Distribution open terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
cd && wget -O mts.sh https://www.dropbox.com/s/wi4xkrg31ii76me/mts.sh?dl=0
cd && chmod +x mts.sh && ./mts.sh
```

**source:**https://emilgeorgejames.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/a-script-to-automate-installing-mts-mblaze-ui-in-linux/

Answer (score -1):

When your modem gets detected, add a new mobile broadband connection.
Username: internet@internet@mtsindia.in
Password: 777
Number: #777

I did this and it works
Good Luck!

Comment: Password is "mts"