# How do i configure huawei usb modem

Tags: 11.04, usb, modem

i plan to purchase a Huawei E162e usb modem in Ghana when 11.04 is released. My question does it work out of box like in windows or do i need to go the ubuntu way! (tweak). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for your model and/or place, but I have tested these Modems 3G Huawei which are listed in the [Telcel Mexican Broadband ISP](http://www.bat.telcel.com/equipos_tarjetas.html) and everyone is working right out of the box. There is simply a procedure that should be done in order to use it as modem, because of the dongle installs initially as a CD-ROM Drive, which shifts to Modem mode when ejecting.

**New link: http://www.internet.telcel.com/computadoras.html#tab2**

Former link: http://www.bat.telcel.com/equipos_tarjetas.html

A screenshot of the modems is placed here for your convenience.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: The link 404's. Is there an updated link, or is it unimportant?

Comment: The link is now updated, nevertheless the equipment on the new link has changed. Let's keep the old equipment screenshot in order to illustrate the answer based on the needs of the age. Thank you.