# How to run MTS mblaze in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 10.04

I connected the MTS Mblaze USB in a PC that runs UBUNTU 10.04 LTS. I found the icon of Mblaze on the screen (setup.exe), I double-clicked it, but it didn't execute because there was an error.

I have to install the g++ compiler package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **setup.exe** indicates MTS mblaze is an Windows program. Ubuntu is Linux. It runs Linux program and cannot run Windows program on its own. Some Windows program can by run with the help of a program called WINE. Install wine using **Ubuntu Software Center**.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16935/how-do-i-set-up-an-mts-mblaze-modem

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Answer is purely theoretical as i don't own such an hardware.

1. Open Terminal (**ctrl+alt+T**)
2. type: **sudo apt-get install wvdial** Type your password and Press y when promted
3. gksu gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
4. Copy paste text below. Save. Close gedit

---

```
[Dialer mts]
Stupid Mode = 1
Inherits = Modem0
Password = MTS
Username = internet@internet.mtsindia.in
Phone = #777
[Modem0]
Init1 = ATZ
SetVolume = 0
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud = 115200
FlowControl = Hardware (CRTSCTS)
Dial Command = ATDT
```

---

Type **sudo wvdial mts** in terminal when you want to connect to internet. You could consider making a script file for automatic and easier connection.

Here is a link explaining how to connect using a MTS MBlaze:
http://nikhilbhardwaj.in/2012/05/06/mts-settings-for-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 0):

1. Click in network manager (See in top right panel)
2. click on "edit connections" then go to mobile broadband
3. Click on "Add". Select All details like country and provider.
4. Now goto mobile broadband tab. Provide user name [user name is - **internet@internet.mtsindia.in** ] and password [password is - **mts**].
5. Now try to connect. Click on network manager and select your connection

Let us know if you have face any difficulties.