# MTS Mblaze datacard in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS connection issue

Tags: networking, internet, usb-modem

I was able to connect only once and use internet.  That time, `lsusb` displayed:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

But after I disconnected the data card and tried to connect, its not connecting to the internet.  `lsusb` now displays:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)
```

I am not able to understand what should I do to again able to connect to internet. Please guide me to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

To use Datacard on Ubuntu OS, find the step below. Read them carefully before you take the step and do not miss the step mentioned herein.
To use  on Ubuntu OS, find the step below. Read them carefully before you take the step and do not miss the step mentioned herein.

1.You try to connect datacard stick and boot up Ubuntu / system.

2.You may choose network connections and click on the 'New Mobile Broadband Connection'

3.Select 'continue' in the dialog box and select "India" as country & then click continue.

4.It will show the list of service providers, select Tata Photon+ (2G).

5.Now, under billing dialog, select the plan as Tata Photon+ (2G) just click 'confirm' and save your settings.

6.After these steps, you will get Network Connections, you will find "Tata Photon+ (2G)" option and click on it. In case if it does not connect to internet then you can just unplug and then plug your 3G stick.

7.That's it the step, now you can enjoy by using Tata photon 3G stick with your Ubuntu OS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1. Mine is MTS MBlaze Ultra Data Card.
2. I have done similar to the steps which you have mentioned. I was able to connect to internet ONCE. But after that I am unable to connect to internet. I have mentioned the two different lsusb output: a) when it connected to internet, b) when I am unable to connect to internet. Please tell me what to do because the steps which you have mentioned worked once but its not working after that.

Comment: @KaushikAcharya: I have seen the similar post in the following link. Please try the same and i pray it should work for you.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/16935/how-do-i-set-up-an-mts-mblaze-modem

Comment: Thanks for the link.

I wanted to try the setup option which involves extracting .deb file. I have questions regarding that:

(1) To extract .deb file, I need to cd into that directory. What should be the directory?

(2) Usually whenever we connect any device using USB, it shows up in Files -> Devices.
But I can't see anything else except "Computer".

Whereas when i give the command "lsusb" in terminal, I see "E1552/E1800/E173 (HSPA modem)"